# Display New Column for Each Row Value

Tags: mysql, count, row

I'm trying to add a new column for each time an account number shows up in my query.  My query below pulls the necessary information and then totals the amount of times a row occurred with the same account number but what I need to do next is have it create a row for each time a dose was given for a patient.

So if I have an account number that pulls up three rows in the table I would like for it to populate a new column displaying the individual value from each row that has that account number in it.

I just need to know what to add to the query below

```
    SELECT LastName, FirstName, PatientNo, COUNT(*) AS 'Occourances Given'
    FROM patient
    JOIN medication ON patient.medication_id = medication.id
    WHERE medication.id = 'variable'
    GROUP BY PatientNo, LastName, FirstName
    ORDER BY LastName
```

This is what I would like the output to look like.  Take the total dose column and break it down and show what the value of each dose was.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: can you show current results example and expected results example please.

Comment: You want to add a new column and you create a new row? Could you possibly give an example of what output you expect to get?

Comment: what column stores `the value of each dose` you do not have this in your original query and you do not show your table structure.

Comment: also, is there a max `Occurances Given`? if there is no set max then you would have to form the query dynamically so then the question is what language are you using php/java/other??

Comment: There is most given is 101. I only know a little C#.  I'm not sure if/how to do that with C#.

Comment: well... I am pretty good with php but don't know any C#. If I posted the algorithm in sudo code maybe you could translate it to C#, I can do that if you tell me where `the value of each dose` comes from. Is ita column in the `medication` table?

Comment: @MattP so looking at this and trying to figure out the table structure is quite odd... you have no pivot table. This looks like it should be a many to many meaning that many medications are given to many patience which would allow a patient to be given many medications as well, but your query makes it look like one to many meaning one medication is given to many patients this would limit each patient to only having one medication unless the record was duplicated as it appears you are doing. Is this in production? If not I suggest database redesign. Or PLEASE post table structure to clarify.